# wi-fi thermostat wiring for Carrier FE4 elec. furnace w/heat pump

Tags: hvac

what is the correct wiring diagram for a honeywell wi-fi thermostat on a carrier FE4 elec. furnace w/heat pump

Comment: I believe this is getting overly product specific and best handled by the manual for the thermostat.

Comment: Have you tried reading the documentation that came with the thermostat?  Did you check inside the furnace for a schematic?  How was the previous thermostat wired?  What wires are available at the thermostat location? How are those wires connected in the furnace?  HVAC wiring is not standardized, so wire color doesn't always mean anything.

Comment: yes i did refer to the user manual for the thermostat it states i need a C wire the original thermostat only used four wires that connect to a four wire plug inside the furnace there are other wires available to use i tried wiring one to the C terminal on the thermostat and to the C connectionon on a different terminal strip inside the furnace didnt work

Answer (score 0):

From what I could find, your unit is designed to only work with specific thermostats ("*User Interfaces*").  It uses a proprietary interface, to communicate between the units.  A four pin ABCD connector is used, to connect the *User Interface* with the furnace.

After doing some research, the pin configuration seems to be:

- A - Data A.
- B - Data B.
- C - 24 VAC (common).
- D - 24 VAC (Hot).

Pins `C` and `D` are used to power the *User Interface*, while pins `A` and `B` are used for communication.  This is a proprietary setup, and likely not compatible with your new thermostat.